# Vertically center text and image in two lines

Tags: graphics, latex, vertical-alignment, xelatex

I need to place a text of two lines next to a centered image.

I have already tried the code provided in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433/vertically-center-text-and-image-in-one-line/17101, which works great for a single line, but cannot get it to work for for than one.

```
\newcommand{\vcenteredinclude}[1]{\begingroup
\setbox0=\hbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{#1}}%
\parbox{\wd0}{\box0}\endgroup}

\par{\hspace{3cm}\LARGE \centering
    {text}{\\more text under text} \hspace{2cm}\smallskip       \vcenteredinclude{myimage}\par}
```

can you please help?

Comment: Dear reviewers, this is a pure tex problem and unrelated to programming. I think it would be best if it would be migrated to tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpler is to use an array IMHO. The array package extends tabular by adding several extra column specifier and one, `m` is like `p` (paragraph), but the paragraph is centered in the cell. So, just put you text in a 'm' paragraph and the image in another.
The resulting code is straightforward.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{m{5cm}m{5cm}}
 mona lisa mona lisa mona lisa mona lisa mona lisa mona lisa 
   &\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{monalisa}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can adjust the width between the image and the text with

`\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2cm}`